# Why does this app from F-droid ask for location?

Tags: permissions, privacy

I find [Syncopoli](https://f-droid.org/packages/org.amoradi.syncopoli/) interesting for backup of own data. It's like rsync for the phone. But it asks for location and I wonder why would the app need it? I'm not terribly paranoid, I'm just privacy aware.

Answer (score 1):

It's spelt out clearly in the `readme` on the app's Gitlab [website](https://gitlab.com/fengshaun/syncopoli/-/blob/master/README.md)

> `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`: unfortunately, Android 8.1+ now mandates this permission AND enabling location services for apps to get the SSID. So, if you are running Android 8.1 and above and want your profiles to sync only when you're connected to a specific SSID, this permission **AND enabling location services** is required.

(Emphasis supplied)

Open source apps usually address such concerns, so it's a good idea to lookup the documentation.